# Kotlin returns 2d Array property as reference

Tags: arrays, kotlin, multidimensional-array, reference

I was messing around with Kotlin and 2d arrays an I detected a strange behavior that I don't understand.
So I have a Class that has a 2d Array as property and I have another class that takes that Array and change it. But now the original Array from the property has changed.

My code looks like that

```
import org.junit.Test

class ClassHasArray {
    val someArray = Array(3) { BooleanArray(3) }
}

class ClassWantsArray {

    @Test
    fun test(){
        val c = ClassHasArray()
        val arr = c.someArray
        arr[1][1] = true
        printArray(c.someArray)
    }

    private fun printArray(array: Array<BooleanArray>){
        for (i in array.indices) {
            println(array[i].contentToString())
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the Test is

```
[false, false, false]
[false, true, false]
[false, false, false]
```

But I was expecting

```
[false, false, false]
[false, false, false]
[false, false, false]
```

because I didn't changed the property from the class *ClassHasArray*

So for me it looks like *c.someArray* is returning the reference of the property. Is there a way to prevent this? I just want a copy to work with, without messing up my property.

Comment: You didn't create a copy of the array, so you operate on the exactly the same data structure.

Comment: @user8637117 You can make a deep copy with: _val copy = arr.map { it.toTypedArray() }.toTypedArray()_

Comment: It may help to recall that Kotlin does _not_ have multidimensional arrays — instead, it has arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of `c.someArray` and also a copy of all elements of that array because those elements are also BooleanArrays, so you can do this by changing this declaration `val arr = c.someArray` to this:

```
val arr = Array(c.someArray.size) { c.someArray[it].copyOf() }
```

With this approach we are going to create a new array containing a copy of the elements of `c.someArray`

Comment: We can avoid additional data copying by: `Array(someArray.size) { someArray[it].copyOf() }`. I miss something like `mapToArray()` extension in stdlib.